# How to access/pass a variable in a nested function in an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm using the `path.aStar` function from this Github library: https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.path. It's a library which calculates the shortest path in a graph. It works fantastically, but is a bit low on documentation for those still fairly new to JS.

I'm using it in a Vue.js framework, and at the moment, I need to specify separate "pathFinder" functions
for each of the different modes I want to calculate my paths because I cannot find a way to get my variables to use it in the path finding function. Let me demonstrate:

I have a number of options which influence how the best path will be calculated (two shown here, but I actually have a few more):

```
    data: () => ({
        indAvoidSea: false,
        shortOrFast: 1,
    })
```

This is how the pathFinder function is defined (simplified):

```
computed: {
    /*
     * cDistance
     *   Calculates the path between this.distLocFrom and this.distLocTo.
     *   Returns retObject containing the distance and path.
     * 
     */
    cDistance() {

        ...

        var pathFinder = path.aStar(this.graphRoads, {
            distance(fromNode, toNode, link) {
                if (link.data.distance_type == 'Sea') { // && this.indAvoidSea <-- here is where I would like to access my this.indAvoidSea
                    // Avoid Sea, increase weight of sea path by 50%
                    return link.data.dist_mi * 1.5
                } else {
                    return link.data.dist_mi
                }
            }
        })
        
        // Calling the pathfinder:
        return pathFinder.find(this.distLocTo, this.distLocFrom)
    },
}
```

So the question is, (how) can I access an 'outside' variable inside the `distance()` function? Referencing this.indAvoidSea results in an error (`Cannot read property 'indAvoidSea' of undefined"`). My current solution is to have a different pathFinder for every possible scenario, but this is getting out of hand quickly and feels like a totally wrong approach.

PS. Not sure on the topic title, is this a nested function in an object?

EDIT. Suggestion from @Mr. Or, this is how I understood that. Results in a `"ReferenceError: distance is not defined"`:

```
        var pathFinder_fastest = path.aStar(this.graphRoads, 
            distance(fromNode, toNode, link => {
                if (link.data.distance_type == 'Sea'){ //&& this.indAvoidSea) {
                    return link.data.hrs_ship;
                } else {
                    return link.data.hrs_walk_normal;
                }
               
        }));
```

EDIT2. Suggestion by tevemadar, results in an `"ReferenceError: data is not defined"`:

```
        var pathFinder_fastest = path.aStar(this.graphRoads, {
            distance(fromNode, toNode, link) {
                if (link.data.distance_type == 'Sea' && data().indAvoidSea) {
                    return link.data.hrs_ship;
                } else {
                    return link.data.hrs_walk_normal;
                }
            }
        });
```

EDIT 3: This works, possible solution!

```
        var pathFinder_fastest = path.aStar(
            this.graphRoads, {
                distance: this.myDist
            }
        );
```

In methods, define:

```
    myDist(fromNode, toNode, link) {
        if (link.data.distance_type == 'Sea' && this.indAvoidSea) {
            return link.data.hrs_ship * 2
        } else {
            return link.data.hrs_walk_normal
        }
    },
```

Comment: You have access to your data throughout the component. Be sure to use 'this' keyword.
Please send your error

Comment: @Mr. Added the error message. Basically I fail to access "this" within that function.

Comment: try this one: distance: (fromNode, toNode, link) => {....}

Comment: @Mr. I've tried that, but doesn't work. I've added the code, as I interpreted it from your comment, in the question above. (fromNode, toNode, link) => {...} is not valid javascript, at least not in this context, so I had to change it a little. The second argument of aStar seems to have to be an object.

Comment: On top of the other comments, `data` is an arrow function right now, you would access its "value" (actually: its returned value) via calling it, `...data().indAvoidSea`. I can't really see why you haven't simply written `data:{indAvoidSea:false,...}` and made it into a function instead.

Comment: @tevemadar, I don't entirely understand the comment, I've tried data().indAvoidSea, as shown in Edit2. But within the distance() function I cannot seem to access data() as well.

Comment: thanks all, but I've found a solution, see EDIT 3

Comment: You got a mistake here: distance(fromNode, toNode, link => ... this means you are calling the distance method with 3 args.
The correct solution is: distance: (fromNode, toNode, link) => ...

Comment: You did my solution in another way in EDIT 3